# How do I run a function with arguments from an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of functions like the following:

```
var runme = function(liked, disliked){ 
  console.log(`i like ${liked} but I dislike ${disliked}`) 
}
```

I have an object with I would like to use to fill in the arguments of the function

```
var obj = {liked: 'apple', disliked: 'pear'}
```

How can I run the function using the object to specify the arguments?

I tried using spread syntax:

```
runme(...obj)
```

But this produces:

```
TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

**How can I run a function with parameters from an object?**

I can't change the functions, as I am creating a wrapper that needs to be able to handle arbitrary functions.

**Edit**: I've edited the post to use 'liked' and 'disliked' instead of 'one' and 'two' as this better shows that ordering matters.

I can use any version of JavaScript, up to and including ES9.

Comment: it is not possible to address named parameter from the outside. instead, you could change the signature of the function and expect an object.

Comment: How about `runme(obj.one, obj.two)`? Properties of objects don't have an ordering you can control.

Comment: You either call it manually or write a wrapper that understands the input object and the function parameter order. In theory this could be generalized, but I doubt it's worth the effort. You could even do something awful like `eval`, but... meh. I wouldn't.

Comment: @NinaScholz Per the question: I can't change the functions. See the question for why.

Comment: There's no trivial way to generalize this in this way. You could (potentially) introspect the functions via the AST and create wrappers that way, or load the functions and transform them during load/transpilation using normal Babel-esque functionality.

Comment: Can you make a wrapper function or you are not allowed to do that?

Comment: @MaheerAli: I am attempting to make a wrapper function, that must wrap around arbitrary functions.

Comment: @MaheerAli the whole point is to make wrapper functions. To me the key issue is how you'd look at an arbitrary object and guess the correct order in which to pass property values to a function. Unless the object have some ordering indication that explicitly says what the parameter order should be, it seems impossible.

Comment: "Ordering matters" -- does that mean your object can be {disliked: 'pear', liked: 'apple'} ? If so, there's no way to solve it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think you're right. Want to add your comment (that we can't inspect functions this way to know the correct order for the arguments) as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: Ordering of object literals in ES6+ are now consistent,.   So if your object literal is also consistent in the ordering of the function,..  You can do `runme(...Object.values(obj))` , but it's certainly not something I'd like doing.

Comment: @jorbuedo Yes that's correct. The order can be `{disliked: 'pear', liked: 'apple'}` and it should still report that pear is disliked.

Comment: @Keith ordering is *consistent* but it's not under explicit control of the program itself; it's the runtime that determines ordering. The life cycle of an arbitrary object means that two objects with the same property names might expose the list of names in different orders.

Comment: Do you need to support production environments? Stuff like build-pipelines and minifier?

Comment: @Thomas No need for uglification or minification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general-purpose way to accomplish this.

If you can guarantee the provenance of the source then you could use an AST operation to build your wrappers during a transpilation or load phase.

If you cannot, then you're *particularly* out of luck, because the parameter names may be mangled, making an object-key-to-parameter-name transformation impossible.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I made a small tweak (AST rather than 'Babel-esque') but you're  on the money here. 

Answer (score 2):

> I can't change the functions, as I am creating a wrapper that needs to be able to handle arbitrary functions.

That's unfortunate, since making them accept a destructured parameter would be exactly what you need.

Unfortunately, the *names* of parameters are not available unless you parse the result of calling `toString` on the function, which is...fraught with peril. You basically need a full JavaScript parser (because parameter lists are complex these days, including possibly containing entire function definitions for default values) and minifiers and such may rename parameters  (changing `liked` to `_0`, for instance).

You also can't count on the order of the properties in an object. (They do have an order, but not one that helps here...or almost anywhere else.)

You've said you need to handle functions whose parameters you don't know in advance, so my various ideas around wrapping functions with utilities that require passing in the names of the parameters won't work. (If anyone's curious, look at the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55419731/revisions) to see those.)

You can do this from `toString` ***if*** we can make several assumptions:

1. The function parameter lists are *simple*. They don't include destructuring or default values.
2. Comments are not used within the parameter lists.
3. Your minifier does not rename function parameters.
4. The functions are all traditional functions, methods, or arrow functions that **do** have `()` around the parameter list (so for instance, `(x) => x * 2`, not just `x => x * 2`).
5. You don't mind that it'll be fairly inefficient (parsing each time).

That's a lot of assumptions and I don't recommend it. But if you can rely on them:

```
// LOTS of assumptions here!
function run(f, obj) {
  let params = /\(([\w\s,]*)\)/.exec(String(f));
  if (!params) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't parse function");
  }
  params = params[1].split(/\s*,\s*/).map(n => n.trim());
  return f.apply(this, params.map(param => obj[param]));
}

run(runme, obj);
```

Live Example:

```js
// Traditional function
const runme = function(liked, disliked){ 
  console.log(`i like ${liked} but I hate ${disliked}`) 
}
// Traditional function with newlines
const runme2 = function(
    liked,
    disliked
  ){ 
  console.log(`i like ${liked} but I hate ${disliked}`) 
}
// Arrow function
const runme3 = (liked, disliked) => { 
  console.log(`i like ${liked} but I hate ${disliked}`) 
}
// Method
const {runme4} = {
  runme4(liked, disliked) { 
    console.log(`i like ${liked} but I hate ${disliked}`) 
  }
};

const obj = {liked: 'apple', disliked: 'pear'}

function run(f, obj) {
  let params = /\(([\w\s,]*)\)/.exec(String(f));
  if (!params) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't parse function");
  }
  params = params[1].split(/\s*,\s*/).map(n => n.trim());
  return f.apply(this, params.map(param => obj[param]));
}

run(runme, obj);
run(runme2, obj);
run(runme3, obj);
run(runme4, obj);
```

That works because `Function.prototype.toString` [is standardized now](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring), and even in resource-constrained environments it's required to include the parameter list (but may well not include the rest of the function implementation).

Comment: @mikemaccana `toString()` will also fail if there's a minification/uglification transformation in play on any of the functions being wrapped.

Comment: @mikemaccana - The code samples are attempts to provide a centralized way to solve the problem in each case, rather than manually implement each solution, since (sadly) you can't reliably solve it just once, it does have to be per-function.

Comment: @mikemaccana - Just for completeness, I threw in a `toString` version and the caveats/assumptions it relies on. Now that `Function.prototype.toString` is standardized, and requires that the parameters be included in the string...

Comment: @mikemaccana - You don't know the parameters of the functions? Ugh. Then yeah, I think you're stuck with `toString` or Do Something Else Entirely™. ;-)

Comment: @mikemaccana - I don't read "arbitrary function" to mean that, but yeah, upvote or not I'll remove what you consider irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @tjcrowder! List of caveats is super useful too. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer Re-written to factor in correct ordering.

So long as your object keys are named to match the paramaters, you can parse the functions like the following: You can see that no matter which order they are passed in, the output is correct;

```js
var obj = {liked: 'apple', disliked: 'pear'}

    var runme = function (liked, disliked) {
        console.log(`i like ${liked} but I dislike ${disliked}`)
    }

    var translateFunc = function (func, args) {
        let funcAsString = func.toString();
        let argNames     = funcAsString.slice(funcAsString.indexOf('(') + 1, funcAsString.indexOf(')')).match(/([^\s,]+)/g);
        let parsedArgs   = [];


        for (let a of argNames) {
            for (let k of Object.keys(args)) {
                if (k == a) {
                    parsedArgs.push(args[a]);
                }
            }
        }

        eval(func(...parsedArgs));
    }

    translateFunc(runme, obj);

    obj = {disliked: 'pear', liked: 'apple'}

    translateFunc(runme, obj);
```

Comment: You can't control the function but you can control the object. Just make sure it matches what the function expects.

Comment: @Lewis You *can* control the object, that doesn't mean you *will* control the object, especially if object entries are created via anything remotely async, like fetches or UI interactions. This means that you'd still need to martial their values under your complete control, which leads to the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. Upmodded. Also tweaked so pear is always disliked even though the order changes, which better shows that you handle order changes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here's another try. I think  it works, but minification of the code will change your function arguments but not the object properties, so you'll need to work around that.

```
var runme = function(liked, disliked){ 
    console.log(`i like ${liked} but I dislike ${disliked}`) 
}

var obj = {liked: 'apple', disliked: 'pear'}

const wrap = runme => {
    const regex =  new RegExp(/\(([^\)]*)\)/)
    const args = regex.exec(runme.toString())[1].split(',').map(s => s.trim())
    return obj => {
        const result = args.map(a => obj[a])
        runme(...result)
    }
}

const wrappedRunme = wrap(runme);

console.log(wrappedRunme(obj))
```

Comment: `new RegExp(/\(([^\)]*)\)/)` => `/\(([^\)]*)\)/`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and just in case this was the issue, here's what resolved it for me...

Instead of:

```
runme(...obj)
```

I needed to spread the object into a new object:

```
runme({ ...obj })
```

Comment: This could be cool, if you added in a test case etc - also does it handle ordering?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- First convert the function to a `string`
- Use `RegExp` to get the arguments of the function.
- Use `split()` to convert the argument string to array of arguments.
- Then use `reduce()` on that array and create a new ordered array having values of given object.

```js
var runme = function(liked, disliked){ 
  console.log(`i like ${liked} but I dislike ${disliked}`) 
}

function wrapper(obj){
  let args = runme.toString().match(/\(.+\)/)[0]
  args = args.slice(1,-1);
  args = args.split(',').map(x => x.trim());
  let ordered = args.reduce((ac,ar) => [...ac,obj[ar]],[]);
  runme(...ordered);
}

wrapper({liked:"liked", disliked:"disliked"})
wrapper({ disliked:"disliked",liked:"liked"})
```